# adding new entry in sqlite database table

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Hi I have written this code for adding new entry in database table. But while running it shows message that no table found.
Please help me if u find any mistake in this code.

```
char *sqlStatement;
sqlite3 *pDb;
char *errorMsg;
ןnt returnCode;
char *databaseName;
databaseName = "Child.db";
returnCode = sqlite3_open(databaseName, &pDb);
if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening the database. Error: %s",
            sqlite3_errmsg(pDb));
    sqlite3_close(pDb);
    return;
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Open Sucessful");
}

//sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO childname VALUES"
//                             " ('%s')",[strTxtFldValue cString],"childname");
sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO childname VALUES  ('%s')",strTxtFldValue);
NSLog(@"sqlStatement....%c",sqlStatement);
returnCode = sqlite3_exec(pDb, sqlStatement, 0, 0, &errorMsg);
NSLog(@"return code %d",returnCode);
if(returnCode!=SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Error in inserting into the stocks table. Error: %s", errorMsg);
    sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"inserted");
}
sqlite3_free(sqlStatement);
```

Comment: a) *childname* is the table name? b) *strTxtFldValue* is a *C-string* or *NSString*?

Comment: are you sure you have created a table with that name? or have you copied database to documents directory?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create runtime database.

```
sqlite3_exec(database,
                 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PersonalDetailsTbl (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,email TEXT,phoneNo TEXT,DOB TEXT,spouseName TEXT,aniversaryDate TEXT)",
                 NULL, NULL, NULL);

sqlite3_exec(database, [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"INSERT INTO PersonalDetailsTbl VALUES(NULL, '%@','%@','%@','%@','%@', '%@')", 
                         name,email,phoneNo,DOB,spouseName,aniversaryDate]
                        UTF8String],
             NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

@user804417 How are u creating the Database table? If u are creating it manually and then adding the database file in the resouce folder, so that may work in simulator, but may give u problem when u run your app on device, so thats the one possibility of getting error like **NO TABLE FOUND**.

Inorder to resolve that try to create the database from withing the application when u lounch the app, this will definately resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute same insert query from your sqlite software, you will get the same result. So there may be a mistake in giving table name in your app. Or may be you are giving wrong database name...

Comment: @EmptyStack a)childname is table name.b)cString portion is commented in code. but strTextFldValue is NSString not cString
@Rahul I have copied the database not its referrence.              @Gaurav am able to insert data into table using terminal.